# Google search results

Tags: java, search-engine, google-search

My study is to get as MANY of the urls that google returns claiming to have info of my search. I look at the source code of the search result page, the urls were hidden by Google. Can anyone help me? Just get me on the right direction.  Using Java

Comment: Turn off JavaScript and look at the source again, it will be much cleaner. Ow, and don't use Chrome. It will not be a walk in the part but at least it's workable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invoke a REST interface to get the Google search results as XML or JSON using the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) (limited to 100 queries / day).

To make the actual request programmatically check out the [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class.